# Unable to change the border color for the entry and editor in maui

Tags: maui

I need the change the border color, outline border color, and also the focused border color of the entry and editor. There is no property available to change it, can you please share the solution to achieve it?

[image]

isn't possible to check or any workaround available?

Comment: May I know on what platform you are using? From the screenshot, it looks like Windows, right?

Comment: It's better to create your own control with your own border.

Comment: Handlers is the way to go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-8.0#customize-a-control